# Why does terraform init happen every time I run plan or apply?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Every single time I run a terraform command it runs `init` first automatically.  I am using remote state in an Azure storage account.  This seems to have started randomly after not touching the project for several months.

Everything works normally otherwise, but it is annoying and slows us down.

Any way to debug why this happens so I can fix it?

```
myhost$ terraform plan

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/azuread from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/random from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of azure/azapi from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/azurerm from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/azuread v2.26.1
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/random v3.1.3
- Using previously-installed azure/azapi v0.4.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.14.0

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
```

Version information:

```
Terraform v1.2.4
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi v0.4.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread v2.26.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.14.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.3
```

Comment: This is not default or even intrinsic behavior, so there must be some kind of wrapper, alias, environment override, etc. happening here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you that is very helpful, I see now terraform is aliased to terragrunt so I'm guessing that is the culprit here

Comment: Just used this same TF project on a fresh tenant and it exhibits the same problem.  Have upgraded terragrunt and providers to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Terragrunt's [Auto-Init feature](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/auto-init/), which seems to be misbehaving in my project for some undetermined reason.

You can disable the feature with the `--terragrunt-no-auto-init` option or by setting `TERRAGRUNT_AUTO_INIT` environment variable to false.  When you do this, it will give a warning instead but proceed anyway.  Not ideal but at least it speeds up my workflow.

```
$ terragrunt plan --terragrunt-no-auto-init
WARN[0002] Detected that init is needed, but Auto-Init is disabled. Continuing with further actions, but subsequent terraform commands may fail.  prefix=[/home/ken/Code/tf/environments/dev]
```